# Vuejs conditional show

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have many sections for different companies product list, I want to add its product in the card, only the section I selected/clicked, but it is showing for all the companies that listed in the page because markup is same. below is my sample code:`

```
<div ="app">
  <section>
    <h2>Company1 Products</h2>
    <p>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="select1 = !select1">Add item 1</span>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="select2 = !select2">Add item 2</span>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="select3 = !select3">Add item 3</span>
    </p>          
    <div class="product-selected">
      <p>Below product you have chosen</p>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 show-products">
        <span v-if="select1">Item 1 Added</span>
        <span v-if="select2">Item 2 Added</span>
        <span v-if="select3">Item 3 Added</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Company2 Products</h2>
    <p>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="select1 = !select1">Add item 1</span>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="select2 = !select2">Add item 2</span>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="select3 = !select3">Add item 3</span>
    </p>          
    <div class="product-selected">
      <p>Below product you have chosen</p>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 show-products">
        <span v-if="select1">Item 1 Added</span>
        <span v-if="select2">Item 2 Added</span>
        <span v-if="select3">Item 3 Added</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        select1: false,
        select2: false,
        select3: false
      }
    }
});
```

` there is forEach directive but not sure how to use it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **v-for** to render a section for each product.

You can then give each product its own flags for which items have been selected.

Perhaps something like this might help:

```
<div="app">
  <section v-for="product in products">
    <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
    <p>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="product.select1 = !product.select1">Add item 1</span>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="product.select2 = !product.select2">Add item 2</span>
      <span class="available" v-on:click="product.select3 = !product.select3">Add item 3</span>
    </p>          
    <div class="product-selected">
      <p>Below product you have chosen</p>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 show-products">
        <span v-if="product.select1">Item 1 Added</span>
        <span v-if="product.select2">Item 2 Added</span>
        <span v-if="product.select3">Item 3 Added</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          name: 'Company1 Products',
          select1: false,
          select2: false,
          select3: false
        },
        {
          name: 'Company2 Products',
          select1: false,
          select2: false,
          select3: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I have a scope of more than 100 companies list with 39 products each. I found Jquery toggle function to work better.